# How to add a line or some separation between username and article

Tags: java, android-studio

In the activity I've created there is a article written by the user and below it directly is the username. there is no line or any kind of seperation between them.
i wish to have some sort of differenciation between the two.

here is the code:

```
      final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    final List<Map<String, String>> articleData = new ArrayList<>();

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ARTICLE");
    query.whereContainedIn("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("FOLLOWING"));
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    query.setLimit(1000);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject article : objects) {
                    Map<String, String> articleInfo = new HashMap<>();
                    articleInfo.put("content", article.getString("ARTICLE"));
                    articleInfo.put("username", article.getString("username"));
                    articleData.add(articleInfo);
                }

                SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(FeedActivity.this, articleData, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[]{"content", "username"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

                listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the XMl:

```
      <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FeedActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm new to android studio, so please elaborate your answer if possible.

thanks....

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to and a new line to the article name.

`articleInfo.put("content", article.getString("ARTICLE") + "\n ");`

You add a new line or (the enter key) with \n. I have also added a space character because sometimes the line does not get shown if they don't have any characters.
I hope this works I haven't used HashMaps very often so message me if not and I will try to help further.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. But i want some kind of differenciating factor between the article and the username. by only leaving a line, username might get confused with the article itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **`divider height`** property:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"   <= //also this line
    android:dividerHeight="2dp" >   <= //this line here
```

and you have to create custom divider in Drawable folder named list_divider:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#8F8F8F"
    android:dashWidth="1dp"
    android:dashGap="1dp" />
</shape>
```

or you can use this code under your username to add line under it:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

Comment: I added new solution in the answer above you can try it and let me know if it worked

Comment: for using the second method, i haven't mentioned my username or article in the xml, i've just kept the listview. So how could i have both the username and the article and also this line mentioned in my xml. or can i also implement this on my java code?   Thanks....

Comment: I edited my 1st answer. Please check that one and let me know.